# Can we put a function within the Dictionary Item () method?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

A serious scenario I have encountered and which is totally made my Script handicapped, which is as below:

```
On Error Resume Next

For IndexSearch = 0 To ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 Step 4

    If ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 5) <> "" Then

        ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 2) = ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 5)

    'Else

        'ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 2) = DicForProcessEndDate.Item(ob9.Cells(RowCount,1))

    End If 

Next

If Err Then

    Err.Clear
    MsgBox(IndexSearch) '4
    ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 2) = DicForProcessEndDate.Item(ob9.Cells(RowCount,1))
    MsgBox(ob9.Cells(RowCount,1)) '47166954
    MsgBox(DicForProcessEndDate.Item(47166954)) ' here i am getting its value
    MsgBox(DicForProcessEndDate.Item(ob9.Cells(RowCount,1))) ' here i didn't see any value for the key ob9.Cells(RowCount,1). Even "47166954" and ob9.Cells(RowCount,1) are same

End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

Could you help me to understand what the issue is? If it really an issue and help me to resolve it by changing the approach here.

**EDIT**

When an error occurs as `Array out of range` from the line `If ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 5) <> ""` the control goes to error handling part,That's perfect but the `IndexSearch` count is increased by `4`. Lets say when `IndexSearch` = 0,then an exception raised and in the Exception block I am getting `IndexSearch` value as for `4` not, `0` -- why so? please tell me!

Comment: @DanielCook Let me give it a try.

Comment: @DanielCook what `clng()` does here ?

Comment: `clng` converts the provided input into a long.

Comment: @DanielCook I collected those values from Excel sheet to dictionary. But with your suggestion it works now. But another issue also occurred here.

Comment: "On Error Resume Next" does not jump to an error handler, nor does it throw an exception to be caught somewhere else. It just hides the error. So your loop goes to the bitter end where the index variable has reached 4. The check of the Err.Number must be done immideately after the suspected statement (in the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that `ob9.Cells(RowCount,1)` is returning a string value.

When you try `MsgBox(DicForProcessEndDate.Item(47166954))` You have hard-coded a numeric value for the key passed to `DicForProcessEndDate`.

The Dictionary Object's key property considers `47166954` and `"47166954"` to be different values. This makes sense because one is numeric and the other is a string.

To avoid your issue, you can convert your key to a numeric value by wrapping it in [Clng()](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_clng.asp). Like so:

```
MsgBox(DicForProcessEndDate.Item(clng(ob9.Cells(RowCount,1))))
```

Alternately, if you wanted to use the string value you could use [Cstr()](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_cstr.asp)

---

Edit: In response to your second question:

You are making an invalid assumption. VBScript error trapping does not work the same as Excel VBA. Specifically, you cannot do something like `On Error goto ErrorCorrection`.

Because of the line `On Error Resume Next` your for loop will continue regardless of whether an error has occurred.

If you want to halt the for loop, like you implied you will need to update your logic to something like this:

```
For IndexSearch = 0 To ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 Step 4
    If ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 5) <> "" Then
        'Check to see if proceeding line caused an error
        If err then
            'Clear the error
            err.clear
            'Exit the loop
            exit for
```

Comment: please see my last **EDIT** and what could be the reason is?

Comment: I understood! You are really nice logic player in this area :-) I am glad to get a help from you!